# jquery reads Nested XML- missing two values

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml

I have nested XML data and I need to output all the values into an HTML file.  I have part of it working - the output for the "contents" section displays, but I can not figure out how to get the "id" and "po" values to show as well.
The XML is coming from another server so I can not modify it.

Half-working example:
https://codepen.io/BIGREDBOOTS/pen/VWQNBw

```
<manifests>
    <manifest>
        <slip>
            <id>2</id>
            <po>123456</po>
        </slip>
        <contents>
            <item>
                <sku>AA100</sku>
                <upc>1234567890</upc>
            </item>
            <item>
                <sku>BB100</sku>
                <upc>0987654321</upc>
            </item>
        </contents>
    </manifest>
    <manifest>
        <slip>
            <id>3</id>
            <po>123456</po>
        </slip>
        <contents>
            <item>
                <sku>CC00</sku>
                <upc>11223345</upc>
            </item>
            <item>
                <sku>DD100</sku>
                <upc>554433221</upc>
            </item>
        </contents>
    </manifest>
</manifests>
```

Here is my script so far.

```js
jQuery(function ($) {
    $("#divContent").append("<p class='mainblock'></p>");
    var mainInfo = [];                    
    $.get("data.xml", function (xml) {
        $('manifest', xml).each(function () {
            var loc = {
                "UPC": $(this).find("upc").first().text(),
                "Contents": {
                    "Item": $.map($(this).find("item").toArray(), function (manifest) {
                        return { "UPC": $(manifest).find("upc").text(), "SKU": $(manifest).find("sku").text() };
                    })
                }
            };
            mainInfo.push(loc);

            $("<div></div>").html($.map($(loc.Contents.Item).toArray(), function (manifest) {
                return manifest.UPC + ": " + manifest.SKU + ": "  + "<br/>";
            }).join("")).append( "<br>").appendTo("#dvContent p");
        });
    });
});
```

As long as the blocks are grouped together I am not concerned with how it looks in HTML.

Comment: Within the `$('manifest', xml)` loop, use `$(this).find('id').text()`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan -  that didn't work - I am still getting undefined.  I updated with a codepen for clarification

Comment: You're doing it in the wrong place. I added an answer for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to retrieve the text from the `id` and `po` elements within the outer `each` loop:

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $("#dvContent").append("<p class='mainblock'></p>");
  var customerInfo = [];

  $.get("https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0453/8489/t/26/assets/sample.xml", function(xml) {
    $('manifest', xml).each(function() {
      var id = $(this).find('id').text();
      var po = $(this).find('po').text();
      var loc = {
        "UPC": $(this).find("upc").first().text(),
        "Contents": {
          "Item": $.map($(this).find("item").toArray(), function(manifest) {
            return {
              "ID": id,
              "PO": po,
              "UPC": $(manifest).find("upc").text(),
              "SKU": $(manifest).find("sku").text()
            };
          })
        }
      };
      customerInfo.push(loc);

      $("<div></div>").html($.map($(loc.Contents.Item).toArray(), function(manifest) {
        return manifest.ID + ' ' + manifest.UPC + ": " + manifest.SKU + ": " + "<br/>";
      }).join("")).append("<br>").appendTo("#dvContent p");
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dvContent"></div>
```